# PHP GMagick: how to get pixel color?

Tags: php, imagick, gmagick

Is it possible to get color of any picture pixel with PHP Gmagick extension?

In IMagick I can get this info from getImagePixelColor method:

```
$color = $img->getImagePixelColor($x, $y)->getColor();
```

How to get this result via GMagick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't currently a native method to do this with Gmagick. This will get the job done though:

```
$img_clone = clone $img;    // No need to modify the original object.
$img_clone->cropImage(1, 1, $x, $y);
$color = $img_clone->getImageHistogram()[0]->getColor();
```

**Returns**

```
(string) rgb(0,0,0)
```